# Nhibernate building query

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I have a query which works in MySql, but I am trying to use it in Nhibernate, where I am facing problem cause I am a noob in Nhibernate.

```
SELECT transaction_table.transaction_id,transaction_table.amount,transaction_table.reason,transaction_table.transaction_datetime,g.status,
       (CASE
         WHEN (transaction_table.user_from IN(0)) THEN 'Paypal'
        when  (transaction_table.user_from<>0) THEN u.user_fullname
       END)as user_name_from ,
       (CASE
         WHEN (transaction_table.user_to IN(0)) THEN 'Paypal'
        when  (transaction_table.user_to<>0) THEN us.user_fullname
       END)as user_name_to 
FROM   transaction_table 
left outer join users u on u.user_id=transaction_table.user_from 
left outer join users us on  transaction_table.user_to=us.user_id 
left join gateway_table g on g.gateway_table_id=transaction_table.gateway_table_id
```

This is the query,

```
var results = session.QueryOver<TransactionTable>(() => transactionAlias)
                .Left.JoinAlias(pr => pr.UserFrom, () => usersFromAlias.Id)
                .Left.JoinAlias(pr => pr.UserTo, () => usersToAlias.Id)
                .Left.JoinAlias(pr => pr.GatewayTableId, () => gatewayAlias.GatewayTableId)
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .Select(pr => pr.TransactionId)
                    .Select(pr => pr.Amount)
                    .Select(pr => pr.Reason)
                    .Select(pr => pr.TransactionDatetime)
                    .Select(pr => pr.GatewayTableId)
                    .Select(Projections.Conditional(
                        Restrictions.Eq(
                            Projections.Property(() => transactionAlias.UserFrom), 0),
                        Projections.Constant("Paypal"),
                        Projections.Property(() => usersFromAlias.FullName)
                    ))
                    .Select(Projections.Conditional(
                        Restrictions.Eq(
                            Projections.Property(() => transactionAlias.UserTo), 0),
                        Projections.Constant("Paypal"),
                        Projections.Property(() => usersToAlias.FullName)
                    )))
                .List<object[]>();
```

I cannot figure out how to proceed after this, this is midway I have been implementing. I cannot find something solid, About XML my mapping might be issue where relations are not mapped, i can't figure that how to do.

Mapping below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="EWalletModule" namespace="EWalletModule">
  <!-- User Table -->
  <class name="Users" table="Users">
    <id name="Id" column="user_id" type="int">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="FullName" column="user_fullname" type="String"></property>
    <property name="Email" column="user_email" type="String"></property>
    <property name="Password" column="user_password" type="String"></property>
    <property name="CreatedDatetime" column="created_datetime" type="datetime"></property>
  </class>

  <!-- Transaction Table -->
  <class name="TransactionTable" table="transaction_table">
    <id name="TransactionId" column="transaction_id" type="int">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="GatewayTableId" column="gateway_table_id" type="int"></property>
    <property name="UserFrom" column="user_from" type="String"></property>
    <property name="UserTo" column="user_to" type="String"></property>
    <property name="Amount" column="amount" type="String"></property>
    <property name="Reason" column="reason" type="String"></property>
    <property name="TransactionDatetime" column="transaction_datetime" type="datetime"></property>
  </class>

  <!-- Gateway Table -->
  <class name="GatewayTable" table="gateway_table">
    <id name="GatewayTableId" column="gateway_table_id" type="int">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Status" column="status" type="String"></property>
  </class>

  <!-- Wallet Table -->
  <class name="WalletTable" table="user_wallet">
    <id name="UserWalletId" column="user_wallet_id" type="int">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="UserId" column="user_id" type="int"></property>
    <property name="WalletBalance" column="wallet_balance" type="float"></property>
  </class>

  <!-- ManageWallet Table //For Admin -->
  <class name="ManageWalletTable" table="manage_wallet">
    <id name="ManageWalletId" column="manage_wallet_id" type="int">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="TransactionFee" column="transaction_fee" type="float"></property>
    <property name="WithdrawalFee" column="withdrawal_fee" type="float"></property>
    <property name="Tax" column="tax" type="float"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Table is simple like the mapping, but the query works in Mysql workbench and data is alright but no idea about Nhibernate.
So currently I get exception issue and I know this is wrong, but cannot figure out how to do it, and I don't want to do it using simple sql query, I will love to do it Object Way.

Thanks to Stack-overflow Community.

Answer (score 0):

Most used overload of `JoinAlias` method has 2 parameters: expression for a navigation property and expression for an alias.

You don't need to specify the "on" condition - NHibernate will resolve it using mapping.

So to do it you have to add navigation properties for `UserFrom`, `UserTo`, `GatewayTable`. You can leave your old properties but rename them to something like `UserFromId` and change type to int(And also check types for other properties: I guess `Amount` should not be a `string` but `decimal`, `double` or `int`).
If you cannot or don't want to add navigation properties then you will have to use subqueries because as far as I know it's impossible to perform join in NHibernate without mapped navigation properties.

```
var results = session.QueryOver<TransactionTable>(() => transactionAlias)
                .Left.JoinAlias(pr => pr.UserFrom, () => usersFromAlias)
                .Left.JoinAlias(pr => pr.UserTo, () => usersToAlias)
                .Left.JoinAlias(pr => pr.GatewayTable, () => gatewayAlias)
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .Select(pr => pr.TransactionId)
                    .Select(pr => pr.Amount)
                    .Select(pr => pr.Reason)
                    .Select(pr => pr.TransactionDatetime)
                    .Select(pr => pr.GatewayTableId)
                    .Select(Projections.Conditional(
                        Restrictions.Eq(
                            Projections.Property(() => transactionAlias.UserFromId), 0),
                        Projections.Constant("Paypal"),
                        Projections.Property(() => usersFromAlias.FullName)
                    ))
                    .Select(Projections.Conditional(
                        Restrictions.Eq(
                            Projections.Property(() => transactionAlias.UserToId), 0),
                        Projections.Constant("Paypal"),
                        Projections.Property(() => usersToAlias.FullName)
                    )))
                .List<object[]>();
```

Also I would suggest you to create a custom Dto model and use ResultTransformer instead of just returning tuples:

```
TransactionDto resultAlias = null;

var results = session.QueryOver<TransactionTable>(() => transactionAlias)
                .Left.JoinAlias(pr => pr.UserFrom, () => usersFromAlias)
                .Left.JoinAlias(pr => pr.UserTo, () => usersToAlias)
                .Left.JoinAlias(pr => pr.GatewayTable, () => gatewayAlias)
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .Select(pr => pr.TransactionId).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.TransactionId)
                    .Select(pr => pr.Amount).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.Amount)
                    .Select(pr => pr.Reason).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.Reason)
                    .Select(pr => pr.TransactionDatetime).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.TransactionDatetime)
                    .Select(pr => pr.GatewayTableId).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.GatewayTableId)
                    .Select(Projections.Conditional(
                        Restrictions.Eq(
                            Projections.Property(() => transactionAlias.UserFromId), 0),
                        Projections.Constant("Paypal"),
                        Projections.Property(() => usersFromAlias.FullName)
                    )).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.UserFromName)
                    .Select(Projections.Conditional(
                        Restrictions.Eq(
                            Projections.Property(() => transactionAlias.UserToId), 0),
                        Projections.Constant("Paypal"),
                        Projections.Property(() => usersToAlias.FullName)
                    )).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.UserToName))
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TransactionDto>())
                .List<TransactionDto>();
```

Comment: Hello @Roman, Can you help me with how to modify my mapping xml so that it should work? I am sorry I am a noob and am having hard time doing it. Thanks for helping

Comment: Actually I don't have an experience with xml mapping. I would recommend you to use [FluentNhibernate](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

What we need, is **the relations mapping**. That is represented by `many-to-one` and `one-to-many`. The doc

#### [5.1.11. many-to-one](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)

#### [6.1. Persistent Collections](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections)

so, for example this

```
<property name="UserFrom" column="user_from" type="String"></property>
```

should be

```
<many-to-one name="UserFrom"   column="user_from_id" class="User" />
<property    name="UserFromId" column="user_from_id" type="Int32"  
                                    insert="false" update="false" />
```

and our entity referencing such User should have properties

```
public virtual User UserFrom { get; set; }
public virtual int UserFromId { get; set; }
```

the second is not needed.. but sometimes could be useful.

Check these:

- [Mapping a column multiple times in Nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13989322)
- [Minimal and correct way to map one-to-many with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29985158)
- [Exclude property from INSERT command in nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26229562)